# Partition key only in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra, I understand that by default, given PRIMARY KEY(id1, id2), id1 will be partition key and id2 will be clustering key.

I want to know if can I define two partition keys without any clustering key as follows:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((id1, id2));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your understanding is correct.
2. Your `PRIMARY KEY ((id1, id2))` is correct and you are specifying **one** partition key consisting of **two** columns.

In the second case, you can query the data only by specifying **both** columns values. EG:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id1=1 AND id2=3;
```

and queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id1=1;
```

will fail because `id2` **is** part of your primary key.